# Error in ReportViewer after deploy ClickOnce - HRESULT: 0x80131401

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5, clickonce, reportviewer

I hope that will help me with this issue.

I have a problem with a application (winforms) build with `.net framework 4.5` and ReportViewer 11 (Reporv Viewer 2012). Ago few weeks I deploy using Windows Azure and install to clients, but when i run a report show me an exception.

```
**An error occurred during local report processing.
Failed to load expression host assembly. Details: Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)**
```

When I deploy in network (LAN) was working fine, but when I deploy via internet i get this error, this error only occurs when i start the application via shortcut .appref-ms, but if I start application executing .exe file show report correctly.

Some else have this problem and how solve?

Thanks.

Comment: I have what looks like the same problem. I have a ClickOnce Winforms app which works fine unless I start it from the ClickOnce shortcut. It even runs properly if I run the exe installed by ClickOnce buried in profile\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ etc.
I've narrowed it down to expressions in a rdlc report. I can successfully run a report with nothing but a textbox with some static text but it errors as soon as I turn the text into an expression such as ="aaa" & "bbb"

I'm guessing that it's got something to do with permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.

I solve this only comment this line, because i dont use ngen ;).
i just comment attribute **[LoaderOptimization(LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost)]** in Main method. This works fine for me, check if you have and comment ;).